# Can't parse 'ksize'. Sequence item with index 1 has a wrong type

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I was trying to extract the horizontal and vertical lines to count them so i used the code from OpenCV
https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/dd/dd7/tutorial_morph_lines_detection.html
and then I wrote this code

```
readImagesFromFile("./ACDB/ACdata_base/9/*")
img = Images[0]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
bw = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, -2)
horizontal = np.copy(bw)
vertical = np.copy(bw)
# Specify size on horizontal axis
cols = horizontal.shape[1]
horizontal_size = cols / 30
print(int(horizontal_size))
# Create structure element for extracting horizontal lines through morphology operations
horizontalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (int(horizontal_size), 1))
# Apply morphology operations
horizontal = cv2.erode(horizontal, horizontalStructure)
horizontal = cv2.dilate(horizontal, horizontalStructure)
# Show extracted horizontal lines
# Specify size on vertical axis
rows = vertical.shape[0]
verticalsize = rows / 30
# Create structure element for extracting vertical lines through morphology operations
verticalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, verticalsize))
# Apply morphology operations
vertical = cv2.erode(vertical, verticalStructure)
vertical = cv2.dilate(vertical, verticalStructure)
plt.imshow(horizontal)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(vertical)
plt.show()
```

then get this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24112/3544565921.py in <module>
     23 verticalsize = rows / 30
     24 # Create structure element for extracting vertical lines through morphology operations
---> 25 verticalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, verticalsize))
     26 # Apply morphology operations
     27 vertical = cv2.erode(vertical, verticalStructure)

TypeError: Can't parse 'ksize'. Sequence item with index 1 has a wrong type
```

[image]

I searched for this in the documentation and I found that I did not call a wrong argument
https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html

[image]

I did not find the error in my search so I hope someone help me with it

Comment: I suppose `verticalsize` isn't an integer in this case, and non-integral kernel sizes don't make sense, hence the error. Looks like you already solved that few lines earlier for the `horizontal_size`, so why even ask the question?

Comment: so i must do it like this `int(verticalsize)` so the horizontal_size ?

Comment: i did not realize that this is the solution because this is the same code in OpenCV documentation

Comment: Sure, that would work. Or use operator `//`.

Comment: Yes, looks like the version of the example you used is still for Python 2.7. If you look at a more recent version of the documentation, it's fixed to work with Python 3.